# Probability Function for Particle Accumulation in a 3x3 Grid

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

I'm looking for the general solution to calculate the number of filled squares in a 3x3 grid at any timestep due to the filling of squares at a constant rate 1 per second. The squares are filled at random and can be filled more than once but only register as filled the first time a particle lands on them.

I have calculated the solution from drawing out a matrix of time step vs possible outcomes. The solution follows a Poisson distribution of all possible probability paths to each outcome. And forms a logarithmic increase over time.

At $t=1$, $P=1$

At $t=2$, $P=1\times\frac19+2\times\frac89$

At $t=3$, $P=1\times\frac19\times\frac19+2\times\frac89\times\frac29+
         3\times\frac79$
Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After $t$ steps, the number $N$ of filled squares is the sum of $9$ indicators: $N = I_1 + I_2 +\cdots I_9$, where $I_k$ equals $1$ if square $k$ is filled by step $t$, and equals zero if not. So the expected number of filled squares after $t$ steps is
$$
E(N) = E(I_1) + E(I_2) + \cdots + E(I_9)
$$
which equals $9E(I_1)$ by symmetry. But $E(I_1)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
E(I_1) &= 1 \times P(\mbox{Square 1 is filled by step $t$})
+ 0 \times P(\mbox{Square 1 is not filled by step $t$})\\
&= P(\mbox{Square 1 is filled by step $t$})
\end{align}
$$
To calculate this last probability, think about the opposite event: the only way square $1$ is *not* filled by time $t$ is if square $1$ is "unchosen" at every step from $1$ to $t$. This opposite event has probability $(1-\frac19)^t$, since squares are chosen at random each step, so
$$
P(\mbox{Square 1 is filled by step $t$}) = 1 - (1-\textstyle\frac19)^t
$$
and the desired expectation is
$$
E(N) = 9\left[ 1 - (1-\textstyle\frac19)^t \right]\,.
$$
This formula agrees with your calculation for $t=1$ and $t=2$.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was more complicated as it didn't agree with my calculation for t=3 but I made a mistake in the calculation.

Comment: The solution agrees with all calculations for t now.
At $t=3$, $P=1\times\frac19\times\frac19+2\times(\frac89\times\frac29+\frac19\times\frac89)+3\times\frac89\times\frac79$